# Cannot connect Myo with Unity project built for Mac

Tags: unity-game-engine, myo

Myo cannot connect with a Unity 5 project built for Mac. It says: `Cannot contact Myo Connect. Is Myo Connect running?`

However, it works in the editor. I'm Using Unity 5. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You're likely building for the wrong architecture. In the build settings, double check that you have selected the x86_64 architecture instead of the default x86.

[image: Unity Build Settings Menu]